# Where do I go after finding a key in Queen Vanessa's fridge?

Tags: a-hat-in-time

Chapter 3: Subcon Forest, Act 4 takes place Inside Queen Vanessa's Manor. Soon after encountering Vanessa for the first time, I found a key in a refrigerator next to a room with a piano.

Queen Vanessa is patrolling the hallway just outside the kitchen. Any time I try to leave, she catches and kills me.

Where am I supposed to go after finding the key in Queen Vanessa's fridge?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That key is for the piano.

If you come close to the piano you'll see the keyhole. After opening it, jump on top of the piano and something will change.

Comment: The keyhole didn't appear for me when the graphics settings were set to low. Thankfully, I was still able to to interact with the piano.